# Socket.IO & Node.js - Broadcasting to all rooms a given user has joined

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is there any *built-in* way to broadcast a message to *all* rooms a given user has joined *except* for the default one? I'm using the following code snippet to achieve this, but I'd like to achieve the same in a cleaner way if possible:

```
for (var room in io.sockets.manager.roomClient[socket.id])) {
    if (key) {
        socket.broadcast.to(key).emit('something');
    }
}
```

Comment: More or less you should be Ok with your solution by any aspect. I can not find an "out of the box" native solution. You can also check https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a native way, but maybe something like (pseudo code):

```
var rooms = {}; (inside client)
on join: rooms[0] = 'roomname'; rooms[1] = 'roomname2'; etc...
for(var i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
    if(rooms[i] != 'default_excludedroomname') {
        io.sockets.in(rooms[i]).emit('message', etc...);
    }
}
```